# Json deserialize with wrapper class

Tags: apex, json, parser

I have created a wrapper class , below is the class

```
public class Wrapperclass {

    public String pictureUrl {get;set;}
    public String publicProfileUrl {get;set;}

    public class basicdetails{
        public string distance {get;set;}
        public string emailAddress {get;set;}
        public string firstName {get;set;}
        public string headline {get;set;}
        public string lastName {get;set;}
        public location locdetails {get;set;}
    }

    public class positions{
        public integer total {get;set;}
        public List<values> comvalues {get;set;}
    }

    public class location{
        public country countrydetails {get;set;}
        public string name {get;set;}
    }

    public class country{
        public String code {get;set;}
    }

    public class values {
        public company companydetails {get;set;}
        public integer Id {get;set;}
        public boolean iscurrent {get;set;}
        public string title {get;set;}
    }

    public class company{
        public integer Id {get;set;}
        public String industry {get;set;}
        public String name {get;set;}
        public String size {get;set;}
        public String ticker {get;set;}
        public String type {get;set;}
    }
}
```

And the Json that has been parsed with this class is :

```
{
    "distance": 0,
    "emailAddress": "surface_alisar@hotmail.com",
    "firstName": "James",
    "headline": "The World news",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "pictureUrl": "https://media.com/mpr/mprx/0__HjzfUue5D1Wo4-9uMLNI",
    "positions": {
        "_total": 1,
        "values": [
            {
                "company": {
                    "id": 876541,
                    "industry": "Information Technology & Services",
                    "name": "Telsa Inc",
                    "size": "400+",
                    "ticker": "TLA",
                    "type": "Public Domain"
                },
                "id": 8766544532,
                "isCurrent": true,
                "location": {},
                "title": "Engineer Department"
            }
        ]
    },
    "publicProfileUrl": "https://www.zip.com/9875/usad"
}
```

I need to display these values in the page so in the controller class i wrote

```
Controller:
    public Wrapperclass wrapperinstance {get;set;}
    wrapperinstance = (Wrapperclass )JSON.deserialize(Jsonstring, Wrapperclass.class); // Jsonstring is the above JSON
System.debug(wrapperinstance);
```

In the above debug i got only

```
  ]|DEBUG|wrappercon: -Wrapperclass: [
        pictureUrl=https://media.com/mpr/mprx/0__HjzfUue5D1Wo4-9uMLNI,
        publicProfileUrl=https://www.zip.com/9875/usad
    ]
```

Why the other values are not parsing/i am not seeing those values.

I am not getting any error; also if i want to use wrapperinstance.basicdetails in the class, it says

> Error: VFcontroller Compile Error: Variable does not exist: basicdetails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your wrapper class and related classes need to look like this:

```
public class Location {

}
public class Company {
    public Integer id;
    public String industry;
    public String name;
    public String size;
    public String ticker;
    public String type;
}
public class Values {
    public Company company;
    public Integer id;
    public Boolean isCurrent;
    public Location location;
    public String title;
}
public class Positions {
    // public Integer _total; // Sorry, can't have _ as the first character
    public Values[] values;
}
public class WrapperClass {
    public Decimal distance;

    public String emailAddress;
    public String firstName;
    public String headline;
    public String lastName;
    public String pictureUrl;
    public String publicProfileUrl;

    public Positions positions;
}
```

This was derived from the original JSON. Consider using [JSON2Apex](http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) in the future to automatically generate the correct code from your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because `basicDetails` is a subclass, and you haven't added it as a property anywhere. Also, your JSON structure and your `Apex` structure don't match up. Remove your subclass declaration and it should resolve the issue.

Change:

```
public class basicdetails
{
    public string distance {get;set;}
    public string emailAddress {get;set;}
    public string firstName {get;set;}
    public string headline {get;set;}
    public string lastName {get;set;}
    public location locdetails {get;set;}
}
```

to:

```
public string distance {get;set;}
public string emailAddress {get;set;}
public string firstName {get;set;}
public string headline {get;set;}
public string lastName {get;set;}
public location locdetails {get;set;}
```

Comment: That still won't quite fix the problem, but it'll get closer.

Comment: JSON2Apex  is realy a good tool. I got it corrected with the right variable names. The names are different and hence facing issues. Thanks guys